# Can you extend initialized models?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

```
class TheModel extends Backbone.Model
    foo: 
        #bar
```

`Entity = new TheModel(#pass in attributes)`

Can I then extend Entity and maintain the models attributes/state?

```
class User extends Entity
    foo: 
        super
        #more
```

EDIT:

```
class Entity extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: (options) ->
        @_events options

        _events: (options) -> 
            entity.bind 'foo'

class Entity1 extends Entity
    _events: (options) ->  
        super options
        entity.bind 'bar'

class Entity2 extends Entity
    _events: (options) -> 
        super options
        entity.bind 'baz'

#a new entity arrives, we don't know if he is type one or two yet so he is...
entity = new Entity

#now we find out he is type 2
entity = new Entity2(entity.attributes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Having a class extend an object (rather than a function) doesn't make sense. If you tried to instantiate your `User` class, you'd get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

If you want to override the `foo` method on `Entity`, you should do so directly, though note that the `super` syntax won't work. Instead, you should write

```
entity.foo = ->
  @constructor::foo.apply arguments  # equivalent to super
  # ...
```

Comment: Yes. Your code will work, except that you'll lose any event listeners bound to `entity`, the new `entity` won't belong to any of the collections the old `entity` belonged to, etc. Generally, you'd be better off either dynamically attaching the `foo` function (as in my answer), or ditching polymorphism in favor of a one-size-fits-all `foo` function that does something like `if @type is 1...`