# Upgrading a Model (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Right now I have a generic User model for all users. When a user logs it's determined wether they are user type 1 or user type 2. These two types need totally different models to represent them but still include everything found in the generic User model.

My goal is up upgrade the User model for each type of user by passing the state from the current User model into the Type1 or Type2 model.

(in coffeescript)

```
class Type1 extends User
    #add super set of methods


#user arrives

user = new User

#after logging in

state = user.toJSON()

#do I need to unbind/delete the current user model?

user = new Type1(state)
```

Is this the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394992/can-you-extend-initialized-models

Answer (score 1):

You could do that. You could also just copy over the `attributes`:

```
userCopy = new Type1
userCopy.attributes = user.attributes
delete user
```

Note that with either approach, you'll lose event bindings, etc. A safer, more JavaScript-y approach would be to just extend `user` in-place with additional methods, rather than having a `Type1` class at all. (Of course, there are downsides to that to, such as losing the ability to invoke `super` from those methods. See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394992/can-you-extend-initialized-models/7395151#7395151).)